# Stopping at a point

Tags: vb.net, rotation

I have a space ship that I want to turn to a destination angle. Currently it works like 90% of the time, but sometimes, it 'jumps' to the destination angle rather than moving smoothly. Here is my code:

```
a = System.Math.Sin(.destStoppingAngle + System.Math.PI)
b = System.Math.Cos(.destStoppingAngle + System.Math.PI)
c = System.Math.Sin(.msngFacing)
d = System.Math.Cos(.msngFacing)

det = a * d - b * c

If det > 0 Then
     .msngFacing = .msngFacing - .ROTATION_RATE * TV.TimeElapsed
     If det < 0.1 Then
         .msngFacing = .destStoppingAngle
         .turning = False
     End If
 Else
     .msngFacing = .msngFacing + .ROTATION_RATE * TV.TimeElapsed 
     If det > 0.1 Then
         .msngFacing = .destStoppingAngle
         .turning = False
     End If
 End If
```

Comment: I don't see the cycle... am I missing something?

Comment: sorry, the code I posted is a function that is continually called if .turning = true

Comment: Looks like VB.NET. @SimonCanning, you should tag your question with the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this. First you need a function to lerp an angle (C code, port it yourself):

```
float lerpangle(float from, float to, float frac) {
    float a;

    if ( to - from > 180 ) {
        to -= 360;
    }
    if ( to - from < -180 ) {
        to += 360;
    }
    a = from + frac * (to - from);

    return a;
}
```

Then, when starting the rotation you have the `duration` and `stoppingangle` as your own parameters. Get the `startingangle` from your object and `startingtime` (in something decently precise, milliseconds) and save them. The rotation then goes like this:

```
current_rotation = lerpangle(startingangle, stoppingangle,
                  (time.now - startingtime) / duration)
```

Comment: I would like to keep my current code if possible... as I say, it works most of the time, i am just not sure why it sometimes doesn't work. I think there will be some simple change that I need to make...

Comment: @SimonCanning: angles are pesky things to work with. What if you're `.destStoppingAngle` and `.msngFacing` are 0 and 180 respectively? Then `det` will be 0. Not exactly what you want.

Comment: Would that be the reason why sometimes it 'jumps' to the destination angle?

Comment: @Simon Canning: perhaps, though I'd have to see for myself in order to tell.

Comment: @Simon Canning: On the left of my answer there is a check button. Click on it.